# Por qué VueJs Almacena setters & getters en un arreglo

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo un formulario hecho, el detalle es que al momento de enviarlo estoy imprimiendo el objeto que genero en la consola y me esta mostrando que para los arreglos en lugar de salir el dato en key pair, sale un objeto de setters & getters y no tengo idea de por que o si repercutirá al momento de que el servidor lo procese

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la diferencia de como lo muestra para el arreglo `flags[]` al arreglo `hints[]` es debido a que estoy procesando el arreglo `flags[]`, a continuacion dejo el codigo:

```js
      onCreateChallenge(){
        const flagArray = []
        for(let i=0; i<this.flags.length; i++){
          flagArray.push({description: this.flags[i].description})
        }
        console.log(flagArray)
        const formData = {
          name: this.name,
          description: this.description,
          maxAttempts: this.maxAttempts,
          challengeValue: this.challengeValue,
          flags: flagArray,
          hints: this.hints,
        }
          this.$store.dispatch('createChallenge', formData)
      },
```

¿podrian decirme por qué es esto?

Comment: No tengo ni idea porque se ve asi. Seguramente tenga algo que ver con la naturaleza reactiva del lenguaje. Pero lo que si es que no impacta en la forma en que usas el array.

Comment: muchas gracias, mi principal preocupacion era que impacte en el uso.